# CSS file not opening in Visual Studio 2010 SP1?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am unable to open CSS files in Visual Studio 2010 after adding to a project.

It shows the following error:

> The operation could not be completed.Unspecified error.

Even if I try to edit embedded CSS in a webpage directly, [IntelliSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelli-sense) doesn't appear.

[image: The screenshot of the error.]

Answer (score 266, accepted):

I found the solution from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/25f9016c-c790-4b8a-b333-5cfdafe45e2d):

> I was having the same issue and found that by **going to the Tools -> Extension Manager -> Online Gallery and search for/install the "Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 sp1"** I was able to open CSS files again.

And it worked for me.

Comment: In my case, I had a corrupt install of the Web Standards Update extension. I couldn't install it from Extension Manager, so I had to go to the [website and download it manually](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83). Once I ran the installer (it defaults to "repair") and restarted Visual Studio, I could edit CSS files again.

Comment: This worked for me too.  My VS was working fine all day until it suddenly stopped opening CSS.  This was a quick fix and everything is good now.

Comment: I already had this installed, but it was apparently corrupted.  Re-installing fixed the problem for me.  This answer should be marked at the proper answer to this question.

Comment: @Abhishek Ranjan, aren't you going to accept this answer? It seems pretty true and highly ranked.

Comment: I got this error after installed ASP.NET 4 RC last week and now it's fixed. Thanks very much.

Comment: Oh, it ws the RC that broke it! I was wondering, as I seemed to have the exact same problem on several machines, both at home and work. And I did have the Web Standards loaded, but I had done that PRIOR to installing the RC. Choosing "Repair" fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Fantastic! I got this after install VS2012 BETA and uninstalling it leavin g 2010 in a bit of a mess

Answer (score 1):

Probably it can happen after installing the Visual Studio [LightSwitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_LightSwitch) beta

OR

Windows [Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure) tools installed

OR

[SQL Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2012) installed

Download this and install it if already installed then repair it and it'll fix the issue:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83

Answer (score 0):

There is dropdown box in the toolbar saying "XHTML 1.0 transition". Change it to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after installing Adobe Cloud production suite. Web Standards Update did the trick.