# VS 2010 does not open CSS files

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css file not opening in visual studio 2010 sp1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731470/css-file-not-opening-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1)

I'm unable to open css file in visual studio 2010.

It's something new, I didn't install anything from the last time it did work, and didn't change any configuration.

Visual Studio says: "The operation could not be completed.Unspecified error".