# Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express "class not registered" error when trying to open a CSS file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-vista, visual-web-developer, visual-web-developer-2010

Visual Studio gives me the following error message when opening a `CSS` file:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express
---------------------------
Class not registered.
Looking for object with CLSID: {D9B3211D-E57F-4426-AAEF-30A806ADD397}.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Opening and editing `HTML` and `JS` files work fine. I found a few suggestions via google saying that reinstalling fixed it. I spent a few hours uninstalling VWD and its pre-requisites and reinstalling it only to get the same error. Does anyone have any insight?

**Update:** attempting to open a CSS file inside a solution gives me a different error message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express
---------------------------
The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new error message led me to this question:
[CSS file not opening in Visual Studio 2010 SP1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731470/css-file-not-opening-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1)

The specific fix for these messages (for me, at least) is to [manually download and reinstall Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83).